# PHP Looping an array and running a function on a array item

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, while-loop

I seem to get this issue a few times and figure it out then the next time I come across it I can't figure it out.

So I have a SQL statement which returns to a $result variable as usual...

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
```

I will show you a slimmed down return below

```
Array
(
    [eid] => 1
    [eTitle] => premier league
    [eDesc] => 
    [cid] => 1
    [deleted] => 0
    [eStartTime] => 15:00
    [eHome] => 1
    [eAway] => 2
    [eKickoff] => 15:00:00
    [eDate] => 2016-08-20
)
Array
(
    [eid] => 2
    [eTitle] => fa cup
    [eDesc] => 
    [cid] => 1
    [deleted] => 0
    [eStartTime] => 15:00
    [eHome] => 1
    [eAway] => 2
    [eKickoff] => 15:00:00
    [eDate] => 2016-08-27
)
```

Now what i want to do is loop through the $result and on each key eHome and eAway run a function below is the pseudo code for what I am trying to do.

```
loop ( $reult ) 

$row[eHome][eHomeData] = $this->getTeam( $row['eHome'] )
$row[eHome][eAwayData] = $this->getTeam( $row['eAway'] )
```

So basically I want to rebuild the array with the home or away team data which uses the id given in eHome and eAway.

Should I do it like this or should I be using JOINS in MySQL?

Sorry if I have worded this badly I having been struggling for a few hours with this and gave up.

Thanks in advance guys.

Tom

Comment: if `$this->getTeam` is another query, then you should probably be using a join. A query in a loop or a query based on the results of another query almost always mean your database\code is structured poorly. But really this is impossible to answer based on the information provided

Comment: so you also want to remove the eAway key after ?

Comment: I think there's not enough information on what data you originally have from where and what the desired output is (and why). There resulting dataset is not much different than the one you've got already... it's just merged into one sub-array.

Comment: If I try to think ahead: I assume `getTeam(id)` supplies all data from that specific team. So I would run a query to get all team-data involved in the first query (`'....where team_id in(1,2,3,4,)'`) and store that into an array with the id a key.

Comment: Sorry for the scrambled question guys, I $this->getTeam($id) queries the database and returns the Team names and data for the teams for a certain event. ie man utd vs chelsea, the first query returns the event with both teams id then the function getTeam I want the data for each team not just the id which is set in the event function which we are currently in

Comment: It sounds like you want to grab a whole dataset based on the id of ehome and replace the id with the dataset? Instead of = try pushing it to an array

Comment: Then you should first query all the teams involved in one go (where id in(1,2,3,4)), or do a join.

Comment: Thank you Jeff that's what I mean.

Comment: And user1854438 thats correct

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have used in the end guys sorry for the poorly worded question. Is there a better way to do this, here is the code and then the print_r() dump for you to see where I was going with this.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('
  SELECT * from events WHERE cid = :cid
');

$stmt->bindParam( ':cid', $categoryid, PDO::PARAM_INT );

if( $stmt->execute() )
{
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    $resultCount = count($result);

    for( $i = 0; $i < $resultCount; $i++ ) {

        $result[$i]['homeTeamData'] = $this->getTeam( $result[$i]['eHome'] );
        $result[$i]['awayTeamData'] = $this->getTeam( $result[$i]['eAway'] );
    }
}
```

Below is the print_r() which adds an extra awayTeamData and homeTeamData with the data collected in the loop added above

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [eid] => 1
            [eTitle] => premier league
            [eDesc] => 
            [cid] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [eStartTime] => 15:00
            [eHome] => 1
            [eAway] => 2
            [eKickoff] => 15:00:00
            [eDate] => 2016-08-20
            [homeTeamData] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 1
                    [tName] => Chelsea
                    [deleted] => 0
                )

            [awayTeamData] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 2
                    [tName] => Man Utd
                    [deleted] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [eid] => 2
            [eTitle] => fa cup
            [eDesc] => 
            [cid] => 1
            [deleted] => 0
            [eStartTime] => 15:00
            [eHome] => 1
            [eAway] => 2
            [eKickoff] => 15:00:00
            [eDate] => 2016-08-27
            [homeTeamData] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 1
                    [tName] => Chelsea
                    [deleted] => 0
                )

            [awayTeamData] => Array
                (
                    [tid] => 2
                    [tName] => Man Utd
                    [deleted] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: what does `getTeam` do?

Comment: getTeam is a function which queries the database brings back in this case the [homeTeamData]  and [awayTeamData] but the function is able to bring back all teams in the database if the $tid is not supplied but if a id is supplied then only one team is returned.

Comment: you should better edit your question, than give this as an answer. Also provide the function 'getTeam'.

Comment: you could still do this with a join

Comment: thanks jeff I will edit in the morning my head is a bit fried from today but i will edit it and see if you or anyone else can improve my answer, a join is probably better for this a dagon says as well. I will edit with the 2 table structures when I get up. Thanks for bearing with me today.